# Is there someway of reducing the code repetition in this situation as is more repetitive than I would like?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm building a number to Roman Numerable converter and wondering if there is a better way to write my switch statement as see there is a pattern and it feels I could do something better with working out what set of numbers I'm in be it 1, 10, 100 or 1000 rather than just adding nested switch statements.

Is the code I have atm:

```
private static RomanValue Ten = new RomanValue(10, "X");
private static RomanValue Fifty = new RomanValue(50, "L");
private static RomanValue Hundred = new RomanValue(100, "C");
private static RomanValue FiveHundred = new RomanValue(500, "D");
private static RomanValue Thousand = new RomanValue(1000, "M");

private static RomanValue Five = new RomanValue(5, "V");
private static RomanValue One = new RomanValue(1, "I");

private static readonly RomanValue[] NumerableArray = new RomanValue[7] { Thousand, FiveHundred, Hundred, Fifty, Ten, Five, One };
public string ConvertNumberToRoman(int val)
{
    var completeSymbol = "";

    while (val > 0)
    {
        var lastDigitString = val.ToString().Last().ToString();
        var lastDigit = int.Parse(lastDigitString);

        switch (lastDigit)
        {
            case 4:
                completeSymbol += One.Symbol + Five.Symbol;
                val -= 4;
                break;
            case 5:
                completeSymbol += Five.Symbol;
                val -= 5;
                break;
            case 9:
                completeSymbol += One.Symbol + Ten.Symbol;
                val -= 9;
                break;
            default:
                if (val >= 10)
                {
                    var last2DigitsString = val.ToString().TakeLast(2);
                    var last2Digits = int.Parse(string.Join("", last2DigitsString));
                    switch (last2Digits)
                    {
                        case 40:
                            completeSymbol = Ten.Symbol + Fifty.Symbol + completeSymbol;
                            val -= 40;
                            break;
                        case 50:
                            completeSymbol = Fifty.Symbol + completeSymbol;
                            val -= 50;
                            break;
                        case 90:
                            completeSymbol = Ten.Symbol + Hundred.Symbol + completeSymbol;
                            val -= 90;
                            break;
                        default:
                            if (val >= 100)
                            {
                                var last3DigitsString = val.ToString().TakeLast(3);
                                var last3Digits = int.Parse(string.Join("", last3DigitsString));
                                switch (last3Digits)
                                {
                                    case 400:
                                        completeSymbol = Hundred.Symbol + FiveHundred.Symbol + completeSymbol;
                                        val -= 400;
                                        break;
                                    case 500:
                                        completeSymbol = FiveHundred.Symbol + completeSymbol;
                                        val -= 500;
                                        break;
                                    case 900:
                                        completeSymbol = Hundred.Symbol + Thousand.Symbol + completeSymbol;
                                        val -= 900;
                                        break;
                                }
                            }    
                            break;
                    }
                }
                var loopValues = defaultLoop(val);
                completeSymbol = loopValues.Item1 + completeSymbol;
                val = loopValues.Item2;
                break;
        }
    }
    return completeSymbol;
}
```

Comment: What about some solutions from google like this one, is it suitable for you [Converter](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/convert-numbers-to-roman-characters-in-c-sharp/#:~:text=Given%20an%20integer%2C%20convert%20it,%3D%2090%20and%20IV%20%3D%204.)

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your code snippet, I'd say the logic for your `while` loop can be described as follows:

---

While `val` is larger than `0`:

- If the **last digit** of `val` is `4`, `5` or `9`:

  - Update `completeSymbol` by *appending* the symbol associated with the **last digit**
  - Update `val` by subtracting the **last digit**
- Else:

  - If `val >= 10` and the value composed of the **two last digits** of `val` is `40`, `50` or `90`:

    - Update `completeSymbol` by *prepending* the symbol associated with the **two last digits**
    - Update `val` by subtracting the value composed by the **two last digits**
  - Else, if `val >= 100` and the value composed of the **three last digits** of `val` is `400`, `500` or `900`:

    - Update `completeSymbol` by *prepending* the symbol associated with the **three last digits**
    - Update `val` by subtracting the value composed by the **three last digits**
    - `var loopValues = defaultLoop(val);` *(original code)*
    - `completeSymbol = loopValues.Item1 + completeSymbol;` *(original code)*
    - `val = loopValues.Item2;` *(original code)*

---

I have a few suggestions about possible refactorings of the `while` loop body. These do not include the three last bullet points (marked with *(original code)*) in the description above.

#### 1.

Exploit the following facts:

- for each value (`4`, `5`, `9`, and so on), there is an associated symbol that will never change for that value. **==> Create a dictionary to store the value/symbol pairs.**
- the format of the calculation of `completeSymbol` and `val` is identical in the case where

  - `lastDigit` is `4`, `5` or `9`
  - `last2Digits` is `40`, `50` or `90`
  - `last3Digits` is `400`, `500` or `900`
    **==> Benefit from having a common source for getting the symbol of each specified value: the dictionary**

I'll name the dictionary `SymbolForValue`:

```csharp
private static readonly Dictionary<int, string> SymbolForValue = new()
{
    [4]   = One.Symbol + Five.Symbol,
    [5]   = Five.Symbol,
    [9]   = One.Symbol + Ten.Symbol,
    [40]  = Ten.Symbol + Fifty.Symbol,
    [50]  = Fifty.Symbol,
    [90]  = Ten.Symbol + Hundred.Symbol,
    [400] = Hundred.Symbol + FiveHundred.Symbol,
    [500] = FiveHundred.Symbol,
    [900] = Hundred.Symbol + Thousand.Symbol,
};
```

Now, this part of your code:

```csharp
// switch (lastDigit)
case 4:
    completeSymbol += One.Symbol + Five.Symbol;
    val -= 4;
    break;
case 5:
    completeSymbol += Five.Symbol;
    val -= 5;
    break;
case 9:
    completeSymbol += One.Symbol + Ten.Symbol;
    val -= 9;
    break;
```

could be generalized to:

```csharp
// switch (lastDigit)
case 4:
    completeSymbol += SymbolForValue[4];
    val -= 4;
    break;
case 5:
    completeSymbol += SymbolForValue[5];
    val -= 5;
    break;
case 9:
    completeSymbol += SymbolForValue[9];
    val -= 9;
    break;
```

, then to:

```csharp
// switch (lastDigit)
case 4:
    completeSymbol += SymbolForValue[lastDigit];
    val -= lastDigit;
    break;
case 5:
    completeSymbol += SymbolForValue[lastDigit];
    val -= lastDigit;
    break;
case 9:
    completeSymbol += SymbolForValue[lastDigit];
    val -= lastDigit;
    break;
```

and hence, be simplified to:

```csharp
// switch (lastDigit)
case 4:
case 5:
case 9:
    completeSymbol += SymbolForValue[lastDigit];
    val -= lastDigit;
    break;
```

Another exploitation of having introduced the dictionary is that you can simply check whether the value exists as a dictionary key, and if so, perform the appropriate calculations. This can be done by using [`.TryGetValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=net-6.0) from the *System.Collections.Generic* namespace.

If we replace the `swith cases` related to `lastDigit` with an `if`, you could simply do:

```csharp
if (SymbolForValue.TryGetValue(lastDigit, out string symbol))
{
    completeSymbol += symbol;
    val -= lastDigit;
}
```

A similar simplification may be done for the existing `last2Digits` and `last3Digits` cases.

#### 2a.

Calculate `lastDigit`, `last2Digits` and `last3Digits` directly, rather than creating and parsing a temporary string.

What you basically want to do when calculating `lastDigit` is to subtract `val` with the value of *`val` rounded down to the nearest `10`*. That means, if `val` is `54`, you can calculate `lastDigit` by subtracting `54` with `50`. `lastDigit = 54 - 50 = 4`.

One way to to get *a value rounded down to the nearest `10`* is to do `10 * (val / 10)`. In the example above, we have:

```
10 * (val / 10) =
10 * (54  / 10) = // int divided by int returns an int
10 * (5)        = 
50
```

Applying this, a naive calculation of `lastDigit` may look like:

```
var lastDigit = val - 10 * (val / 10);
```

Now, this calculation would *not* work well when `val < 10` (seeing as the value inside the parentheses would result in `0`, leaving the calculation to be `val - 0`).

Therefore, you may let `lastDigit` be equal to `val` if `val < 10`:

```
var lastDigit = val < 10
    ? val
    : val - 10 * (val / 10);
```

#### 2b.

Recognize that the calculation of `lastDigit`, `last2Digits` and `last3Digits` is identical except for the *factor*, and extract the calculation of the `last X digit(s)` variables into a method.

The *factor* is `10` when calculating `lastDigit`, `100` when calculating `last2Digits` and `1000` when calculating `last3Digits`. Each of these values can be calculated when you know how many of the last digits that are desired:

- 1 digit: `10 to the power of 1 = 10`
- 2 digits: `10 to the power of 2 = 100`
- 3 digits: `10 to the power of 3 = 1000`

A method for the calculation of `last X digit(s)` could therefore take `val` and the number of desired digits as input parameters. I'll name the method `GetLastDigitsAsInt()`:

```csharp
private static int GetLastDigitsAsInt(int number, int digitCount)
{
    var factor = (int)Math.Pow(10, digitCount);

    return number < factor
        ? number
        : number - factor * (number / factor);
}
```

Now, the `last X digit(s)` calculations can be made as follows:

```csharp
var lastDigit   = GetLastDigitsAsInt(val, 1);
var last2Digits = GetLastDigitsAsInt(val, 2);
var last3Digits = GetLastDigitsAsInt(val, 3);
```

---

Applying all of the suggested simplifications, the content of the `while` loop could now look like the following, having replaced the `switch statement` by `if`/`else` conditions:

```csharp
while (val > 0)
{
    var lastDigit = GetLastDigitsAsInt(val, 1);
    
    if (SymbolForValue.TryGetValue(lastDigit, out string symbol))
    {
        completeSymbol += symbol;
        val -= lastDigit;
    }
    else
    {
        var last2Digits = GetLastDigitsAsInt(val, 2);
        var last3Digits = GetLastDigitsAsInt(val, 3);
        
        if (SymbolForValue.TryGetValue(last2Digits, out string symbol2))
        {
            completeSymbol = symbol2 + completeSymbol;
            val -= last2Digits;
        }
        else if (SymbolForValue.TryGetValue(last3Digits, out string symbol3))
        {
            completeSymbol = symbol3 + completeSymbol;
            val -= last3Digits;
        }
        
        // original code:
        var loopValues = defaultLoop(val);
        completeSymbol = loopValues.Item1 + completeSymbol;
        val = loopValues.Item2;
    }
}
```

An improvement of the suggested implementation may be to only calculate `last2Digits` if `val >= 10` and only calculate `last3Digits` if `val >= 100`. I have not done that in the favor of reducing nesting.

> **Note:**
> This is only a refactoring which was done by hand, it has not been tested with input values and may be faulty. Nonetheless, the observations regarding the dictionary and simplification of calculating the *last X digit(s)* values hopefully bring something to the table.